# Python swapping and slicing method

Tags: python, slice, swap

How do I find the last number of the list and then that number will take the top x number of card and place it at the bottom for example `cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 27, 28, 5, 6, 7, 2]` and since 2 is last number it will get the first 2 card and place it at the bottom before it so it will turn to `[3, 4, 27, 28, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2])`.

I also have the swap function but not sure how to use it since it takes a list and a index and swap the list by the index with the next number.

There is also a special case of when the `[-1]` value is 3 it will swap with the value of 2 but not changing the number

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3] -> [3,4,5,6,1,2,1,2,3]

```
def top_to_bottom(cards)
    cards = cards.index(end)

def swap_me(cards, index)
    if index == len(cards) - 1:
        index2 = 0
    else:
        index2 = index + 1
    cards[index], cards[index2] = cards[index2], cards[index]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

If last index is valid, i.e. there are at least that much cards to move in the array then you can do this:

```
def move_cards(cards):
    if cards[-1] == 3:
        return cards[2:-1] + cards[-3:-1] + [3]
    else:
        return cards[cards[-1]:-1] + cards[0:cards[-1]] + [cards[-1]]

move_cards([1, 2, 3, 4, 27, 28, 5, 6, 7, 2])
[3, 4, 27, 28, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2]

move_cards([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3])
[3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: what if the last number is random like it can be any given list

Comment: Then it will run too. Please try to understand the code.

Comment: what if i want to add special case for it so when the end number is 2 it will switch place with the value 1 so
cards [1,2,3,4,27,28,5,6,7,2] = [2,3,4,27,28,5,6,7,1,2]
which im guessing would have if statement like
    if 2 is in cards[-1]

Comment: It will still run when you add a special case. Of course you would have to write code to handle the special case.

Comment: but how could you run it with just replacing the value not the number itself 
like how can it be  [2,3,4,27,28,5,6,7,1,2] instead of  [2,3,4,27,28,5,6,7,1,1] since it replaces the value not the number

Comment: @itachi123 your question was straight-forward but now I'm getting confused by your comments. The code is very simple. You only need to understand how negative index and slice operator `:` work. But I'm not getting what you meant by your special cases. You should better edit your question with all use cases and explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok im new sorry i just editted my question and added a special case for it 
thanks :)

Comment: Or even better: Create a new question instead of altering this one to something which might end up quite different than the original question.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will swap with the value of 2 but not changing the number"? Sorry, I'm still failing to understand the example for this case.

Comment: like the end number 3 would still be at the end but instead of having 3 top number move to the end it will have 2 since its a special case so it will be  [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3] -> [3,4,5,6,1,2,1,2,3] only the first 2 number is moved

Comment: @itachi123 use a simple `if-else` block. Check the edit.